# react bootstrap tooltip, how do I fire it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Have added a tooltip and trigger to my component, how can i get it to fire the tooltip?

required modules like this:

```
var Icon = require('./Icon'),
Tooltip = require('./Tooltip'),
Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button,
OverlayTrigger = require('react-bootstrap').OverlayTrigger;

getTooltip: function() {

    return <Tooltip text="sample text" />;
},
```

Rendering trigger like this:

```
<OverlayTrigger placement="right" overlay={this.getTooltip()}>
       <Button bsStyle="default">Button text to trigger</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

But nothing happens?

How can I get this to fire?

Thanks

Tooltip component is:

```
var TooltipBS = require('react-bootstrap').Tooltip;

var Tooltip = React.createClass({

render: function() {

    return (
        <TooltipBS>
            {this.props.text}
        </TooltipBS>
    )
}
});

module.exports = Tooltip;
```

Comment: Actually you can do it with css. Just return another style for specific divs

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using react-bootstrap tooltip?

If you read the documentation here http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips-in-text you can see how to use it in your code.

```
<OverlayTrigger placement="right" overlay={this.getTooltip()} trigger="click">
       <Button bsStyle="default">Button text to trigger</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

You can add preferred trigger event with `trigger` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using react tooltip, i have used your code and get no tooltip, any ideas?

Comment: If you use the button and overlayTrigger from react-bootstrap I would recommend to also use the tooltip from react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
getTooltip: function() {

    return <Tooltip id="tooltip">sample text</Tooltip>;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a render() within the component class. Then you will need a `ReactDOM.render(<Tooltip />, document.getElementById('app');` outside of the class.